# How to make Python code write once, run anywhere?

Tags: python, ironpython, jython

I am learning Python. My intentions are:

1. to write a webapp in Python/Django
2. create an android app (using Jython)
3. write some python scripts for unix box

I was under (incorrect) impression that because Python has been implemented in Java (Jython) and .NET (IronPython), I could simply write my Python code and run it through either interpreter/compiler.

I thought if I wrote a hello world in CPython and compiled it with Jython, I'd get Java bytecode. If I compliled it with IronPython, I'd get .NET bytecode.

But now it seems like regular Python code won't work with Jython compiler/interpreter. You've to import some fancy Java specific modules. So, that means, I would have to re-write my program for Java using Java modules/libraries.

Any tips on how to write my Python code so that it works everywhere? Web, Unix, Android.

NOTE: I don't want to have to learn Java.

Thanks

Comment: Why are linebreaks missing from point 1,2,3? Does this SO site not count <enter> key as linebreak?

Comment: Markdown can be a little finicky until you're used to using it. Adding more whitespace almost always makes it happier. :)

Comment: Jython and IronPython are Python implementations. They don't export Java or CLI bytecode, they implement the Python language.

Comment: Say, I write some Java code using standard libraries. Now, I can compile this and produce some .class files. These .class files can be deployed on JVM. JVM could be running on UNIX, Windows, Mobile Device. I won't need to worry. Similarly, I thought if I wrote Python code and compiled it using Jython compiler (instead of CPython interpreter). I will get .class files. These .class files can be deployed over any JVM running on any device. Turns out, .py files are unlikely to compile in Jython without some Java specific modifications. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print 'Hello, World!'
```

This works just fine on any Python implementation worthy of the name. So will most other pure-Python code. Where it gets tricky is when using libraries, as Jython and IronPython are missing some standard library modules and don't support C extensions. Dealing with platform-specific code can also present some issues.

If you want your code to be portable, you need to remove as many dependencies as possible from the shared code. The standard library is generally OK (but not complete in either), and pure-Python external modules are generally OK if they only depend on other pure-Python modules.

If you do need to detect them, I believe the canonical checks are:

```
if os.name == 'java': # Jython
if sys.platform == 'cli': # IronPython
```

---

Neither Jython nor IronPython will produce programs that will run without Jython/IronPython being present. In principle it's possible, and it's even possible to compile a subset of Python to pure bytecode; the former requires linking in the Python engine, and the latter would require restricting what parts of Python you could use.

If someone were to provide this for IronPython I wouldn't turn it down, and I doubt the Jython team would either, but I'm not holding my breath. Either option is *a lot* of work.

Answer (score -1):

Please be more specific about what you are trying to do. What is your regular Python code ? What does not work with it as you expected ?

According to the [Jython FAQ](http://wiki.python.org/jython/JythonFaq/GeneralInfo#Is_Jython_the_same_language_as_Python.3F), Jython is an implementation of the Python language. The same Python code should produce the same result on Jython or CPython.

Comment: Exactly. Except that's not the case. Let me explain:
Say, I write some Java code using standard libraries. Now, I can compile this and produce some .class files. These .class files can be deployed on JVM. JVM could be running on UNIX, Windows, Mobile Device. I won't need to worry.

Similarly, I thought if I wrote Python code and compiled it using Jython compiler (instead of CPython interpreter). I will get .class files. These .class files can be deployed over any JVM running on any device. Turns out, .py files are unlikely to compile in Jython without some Java specific modifications. :(